# In android how to create a background servies

Tags: android

when mobile boot up complete services is going on background and send a mobile imei number through sms

Answer (score 3):

Please go through the below link
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=356

I think this can give you idea in writing a service in android

Thanks
Abi